# Why is MVC Html.RadioButton working like a checkbox instead of like a radio button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In these code I have a strange situation:

```
@foreach (var subs in getSubscriptionTypes())
{
    <p>@Html.RadioButton(subs.LengthMonths.ToString(), subs.Price) @subs.LengthMonths</p>
}
```

I get properly all of `subs`, but radiobuttons behave very strange - I can check all of radiobuttons, but I want to check only one (one is `true`, then rest is `false`). How to repair it?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of each radio button needs to be the same for them to be mutually exclusive (see [this demo](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio)).

So try:

```
<p>@Html.RadioButton("subtype", subs.Price) @subs.LengthMonths</p>
```

For a better user interface, you could also add a [label element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) using `@Html.Label(...)` so that the user can click on the text to select the radio:

```
<p>
    @Html.RadioButton("subtype", subs.Price, new { id = "subtype-" + subs.Price })
    @Html.Label("subtype-" + subs.Price, @subs.LengthMonths)
</p>
```